# Input link into ng-repeat AngularJS and Play Scala Framework

Tags: mysql, angularjs, playframework

I have an ng-repeat where I am displaying product information and I want to display an outside url for each individual product to their display on amazon. The properties below for product url, name, storeFrontPrice, and oneline are all loading to the page properly from the MySQL database. The code currently looks like (the ng-model for query is in code above what's included):

```
<div ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts = (products | filter:query)" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="item-in-grid">
               <a ui-sref="base.index.products.detail({url:product.url, selectedProduct:product})">
                  <div class="product-hover"> <!-- trick to allow us to highlight background on hover -->
                     <!-- picture -->
                     <img ng-src="products/{{product.url}}/image" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Qwik CO"/>
                     <!-- description -->
                     <div class="item-description-section">
                        <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
                        <p class="item-description">
                           {{product.oneline}}
                        </p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="item-price">
                     {{product.storeFrontPrice | currency}}
```

but when I try to change the  tag to this:

```
<a ng-href="{{amazonurl}}">
```

or

```
<a href="{{amazonurl}}">
```

Nothing shows up on screen. I don't receive any errors and nothing comes up in the console. I know just based on the other data appearing and the fact that I can edit price in MySQL db and have changes reflected that the calls to the database are occurring. I looked at the scope and it looks like it should be working as well:

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('app').controller('productsController', productsController);
   productsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Product', 'pageHeaderService'];
   function productsController($scope, Product, pageHeaderService) {
      pageHeaderService.setHeaderInfo({title: "XXXXX", desc: "Below are products that you can use in your home", visible: true});
      $scope.query = "";
      $scope.products = [];
      $scope.loading = true;
      Product.enabledProducts({}, function(response) {
         $scope.products = response;
         $scope.loading = false;
      },
      function(error) {
         $scope.err = error;
         $scope.loading = false;
      });

      $scope.clearFilter = function() {
         if ($scope.query) {
            $scope.query = "";
         }
      };
   }
})();
```

It looks like it is just pushing the response from the server into the products array, where I would assume the amazonurl column would be available just like the other options. I checked to make sure the database connection was set up in application.conf and it looks to be correct, and it points to a call to another location on the server where it appears this information is being served (changing some info to x's to obscure, but those names are all the same):

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxxx"
db.default.username="xxxx"
db.default.password="xxxx"

db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5

db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=1
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds


db.default.queryExecuteTimeLimit=1 second

jdbc-execution-context {
   fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 1
      parallelism-max = 5
      parallelism-factor = 1.0
   }
}

mec.central.endpoint="http://localhost:9010"
```

The application.conf file for that directory also seems to be setup to do so correctly:

```
http.port=9010


application.langs="en"


db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mec_store?serverTimezone=UTC"
db.default.username="mec_store"
db.default.password="mec_store"


db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5

db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=1
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds


db.default.queryExecuteTimeLimit=1 second

jdbc-execution-context {
   fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 1
      parallelism-max = 5
      parallelism-factor = 1.0
   }
}
```

and I checked the db by going into the mysql console on the db server and making sure selecting that table returned my amazonurl column and it does.
On that port 9010 location the model appears to be setup for the product:

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Table(name="product")
public class Product extends AbstractModel {

   @Column(name="name", length=128, nullable=false)
   private String name;
   
   @ManyToOne(optional=false)
   @JoinColumn(name="store_front_id", nullable=false)
   private StoreFront storeFront;
   
   @Column(name="stock_id", length=16, nullable=false)
   private String stockId;
   
   @Column(name="url", length=256)
   private String url;
   
   @Column(name="price", precision=10,scale=2, nullable=false)
   private BigDecimal cost;
   
   @Column(name="price_augment", precision=10,scale=2, nullable=false)
   private BigDecimal priceAugment;
   
   @Transient
   private BigDecimal storeFrontPrice;
   
   @Column(name="description", length=1000, nullable=false)
   private String description;
   
   @Column(name="oneline", length=256, nullable=false)
   private String oneline;
   
   @Column(name="spec", length=1000, nullable=false)
   private String spec;

   @Column(name="enabled", nullable=false)
   private boolean enabled = false;
   
   @Column(name="hazardous", nullable=false)
   private boolean hazardous = false;
   
   @Column(name="weight", length=10, nullable=true)
   private String weight = "0";

   @JsonIgnore
   private String dimensions = "0";
   
   @Transient
   private List<ProductHistory> productHistories;
   
   @Transient
   @JsonIgnore
   private Dimensions dimension;
   
   @Column(name="modifier", nullable=false)
   @JsonIgnore
   private double modifier;

   private static Finder<Long, Product> finder = new Finder<Long, Product>(Long.class,
         Product.class);

   public static List<Product> findAllProducts() {
      return finder.all();
   }
```

If you follow the routes through the controllers you can get to the function in the api call to the mec.central.endpoint seen above. I'm picking up this responsibility third hand as a developer so I don't have a strong familiarity with this Play framework and it doesn't appear to be heavily supported/used. I believe that this is calling the api and passing this info from port 9010 to 9000, as this model.java file does not exist in the first site directory. Do I need to add the amazonurl to this model in order to use it on that site?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for anyone who may look in the future was yes, this model file needed to contain the information pulled from the db identified as well as the methods for creating and updating the amazonurl string when performed through UI.